# How do I avoid two sentences with the same first letter being beside each other in a shuffle?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a code that I've written which shuffles a text file of music tracks, how do I adapt my code so that each time I run the program, there won't be two tracks beside each other that start with the same first letter. For example, two tracks by the artists Hozier shouldn't be beside each other.

Correct:

```
Hozier - Take Me To Church
Pink - So What
Hozier - Cherry Wine
```

Incorrect:

```
Hozier - Take Me To Church
Hozier - Cherry Wine
Pink - So What
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Accepts: command line input
// Returns: 0 if no error

int main(int num_args, char *arg_strings[])
{
    int x = 0, i, track_count = 0;
    unsigned long Max_Length = 0;
char line[500], *temp;
FILE *file = fopen("InputFiles/playlist.txt", "r" );
/* The next line checks if the playlist file exists and if it's not there, "Cannot Open File" is printed to the screen */
if (file == NULL){
    printf("Cannot open file\n");

}
/* The following code identifies each line in the text and lines are shuffled accordingly */

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
{
    track_count++;
    if (strlen(line) > Max_Length)
        Max_Length = strlen(line);
}
rewind(file);
char *Array[track_count];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
{
    Array[x] = malloc(strlen(line));
    if (Array[x] == NULL){
        printf("A memory error occurred.\n");
        return(1);
    }
    strcpy(Array[x], line);
    /* change \n to \0 */
            Array[x][strlen(Array[x])-1] = '\0';
            x++;
        }

    printf("The original playlist is:\n");
    for (x = 0; x < track_count; x++)
    printf("%2d %s\n", x, Array[x]);
/*  The array will now be shuffled: */
srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL));
for (x = track_count - 1; x >= 0; x--){
    i = (int) rand() % track_count;
    temp = Array[x];
    Array[x] = Array[i];
    Array[i] = temp;
}
printf("\nShuffled Array\n");
for (x = 0; x < track_count; x++)
    printf("%2d %s\n", x, Array[x]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `Array[x] = malloc(strlen(line));` should be `Array[x] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);`

Comment: You realize that it might not always be possible to do so (at least without repeating some tracks)? What do you intend to do in such cases?

Comment: It is easy enough to work out that a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of such shuffles is that no letter of the alphabet occurs more than `ceiling(n/2)` times (where `n` is the number of distinct tracks). Necessity is obvious and sufficiency can be proven by induction on the number of distinct letters, with n = 2 a basis case.

Comment: If you want to shuffle them so that all permutations which satisfy the constraint (assuming that there are any such) are equally likely then you have some hard algorithmic work ahead of you (unless you are satisfied with the hit-and-miss approach which might have a low probability of success for some parameter choices). On the other hand, if you simply want to satisfy the constraints in a way that has a fair amount of randomness, then you have a much easier problem.

Answer (score 1):

If repetitions of the same song were allowed (e.g., as when a music player is on both shuffle and repeat), you could just remember the previous first letter and pick each successive song randomly out of those that do not have the same first letter as the previous song.

However, for shuffling the songs without repetitions, considering only the last position does not work, e.g., if your songs had the first letters `C A C B C A C`, they could end up as `A B A C C C C` where you only have `C`-songs remaining at the end. You could detect this situation (i.e., number of unshuffled songs not beginning with the previous first letter is zero) and in those cases find the positions in the previously sorted list into which each new song can be inserted, and pick randomly from those. For example, if you had the above first letters and were at `A B A C`, then the next song beginning with `C` could be inserted into 3 different positions (`C A B A C`, `A C B A C`, or `A B C A C`).

Comment: If I had to implement the latter solution in C, I would probably use linked list as the data structure, at least for the output. Insertions would be quite a bit simpler to implement, and it would not have much of a performance penalty as linear iteration to find the possible "slots" would be required in any case.

Comment: I had similar thoughts about insertions and linked lists. In the comments when I suggested that you could prove that the obvious restriction on the most common letter is also sufficient by using induction on the number of distinct letters I had a (not quite worked-out) insertion idea behind that statement. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use 256 bucket sub-lists.

I'll try coding later if I can.  Thought the algorithm was worth posting.

Pseudo code:

1. Input `n` data into 1 of 256 lists `Array[first letter][]`.
2. Put each of the non-empty lists in a priority queue as in step 3
3. Put lists in into a priority queue of lists based on greatest # of items in list.
4. Extract greatest list from queue, call it `G1`.  Remove 1 item from that list and put in `ArrayB[]`.
5. Extract greatest list from queue, call it `G2`.  Remove 1 item from that list and put in `ArrayB[]`.
6. Put G1 back into the priority queue if not empty.
7. `G2` now becomes `G1`.
8. Continue with step 5 until queue is empty.
9. Continue with step 7 until G2 empty.
10. At this point we now have a list `ArrayB[]`, although not random., that meets the criteria, if possible.
11. Go through `ArrayB[]`, say `3*n` times, randomly swapping a pair of itmes if the swap meets the no-repeat condition.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with sth like this, seems to work but idea needs to be improved ( what if all tracks start with the same letter? some limit of attempts can be added )

```
for (x = track_count - 2; x > 1; x--){
    while( 1 )
    {
        i = rand() % ( track_count - 1 ) + 1;
        if( Array[x+1][0] == Array[i][0] )
            continue;
        if( Array[x-1][0] == Array[i][0] )
            continue;
        if( Array[i+1][0] == Array[x][0] )
            continue;
        if( Array[i-1][0] == Array[x][0] )
            continue;

        temp = Array[x];
        Array[x] = Array[i];
        Array[i] = temp;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will be out of bounds twice with this, regardless of an infinite event.

Comment: Thanks for that, although it doesn't work in my case where I have songs of multiple artists. The programme only has to work with the following list of songs: Taylor Swift     - Everything Has Changed,
Mumford and Sons - Little Lion Man,
Hozier           - Sedated,
Mumford and Sons - Babel,
Taylor Swift     - I Knew You Were Trouble,
Taylor Swift     - We Are Never Ever Getting Back Together,
Hozier           - Jackie and Wilson,
Hozier           - Take Me To Church,
Hozier           - Angel of Small Death & The Codeine Scene,

Comment: You are right, but it seems to work for me now with your list

Comment: Oh, when I do it it only prints Mumford & Sons, where it should shuffle all of them but just no two tracks from the same artist should be beside each other.

Comment: ./a.out Shuffled Array
 0 Taylor Swift - Everything Has Changed
 1 Mumford and Sons - Little Lion Man
 2 Hozier - Take Me To Church
 3 Taylor Swift - We Are Never Ever Getting Back Together
 4 Hozier - Angel of Small Death & The Codeine Scene
 5 Mumford and Sons - Babel
 6 Hozier - Sedated
 7 Taylor Swift - I Knew You Were Trouble
 8 Hozier - Jackie and Wilson

Comment: here is link to full code and input file to make sure we are having the same thing: http://pastebin.com/yBLUaCEY http://pastebin.com/5Eqg6bcL

Comment: You can add number of attempts of shuffling in this endless `while` loop so it will not hang forever in case of too many tracks starting from same letter

Answer (score -2):

The following function "isValidOrder" detects, whether the songs are shuffled in a valid order. It uses the sequence " - " as a seperator for the artist. Dependend on your performance you may just want to shuffle the songs again if an invalid order is detected or may want to modify this code. Use it like this: "isValidOrder(Array, track_count)". if the order is valid, it returns 1 - else 0.

```
int isSameArtist(char * artist1, int artist1Length, char * artist2, int artist2Length){
    if (artist1Length != artist2Length) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < artist1Length; i++) {
        if (artist1[i] != artist2[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int getLengthOfArtist(char * title){
    int length = 0;
    while (*title != '\0') {
        if(title[0] == ' ' && title[1] != '\0' && title[1] == '-' && title[2] != '\0' && title[2] == ' '){
            return length;
        }else{
            title ++;
            length ++;
        }
    }
    return length;
}

int isValidOrder(char ** Array, int track_count){
    if (track_count == 0)
        return 1;
    char * artist = Array[0];
    int artistLength = getLengthOfArtist(artist);
    for (int i = 1; i < track_count; i++) {

        char * nextArtist = Array[i];
        int nextArtistLength = getLengthOfArtist(nextArtist);
        if (isSameArtist(artist, artistLength, nextArtist, nextArtistLength) == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        artist = nextArtist;
        artistLength = nextArtistLength;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: please note that if you decide to shuffle the code again it may happend, that a valid order is never detected. This might be the case if you have 4 songs of Hozier and one of Pink in your playlist. For such a case I would try it x times and then just let the playlist the way it is. Given that performance is not a problem.